# How to pass unknown Proc recursively in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, lambda, proc

## Problem

I am trying to write a method (Array#bubble_sort), that takes in an optional proc argument. 
  When given a proc, the method should sort the array according to the proc. 
  When no proc is given, the method should sort the array in increasing order. 
 Recursively, this works fine without adding a proc, however when given an unknown proc, I cannot find a way to pass it back through as an argument correctly.

## Code

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort(&prc)

    prc = Proc.new{|a,b| a <=> b} if !prc

    self.each_with_index do |ele,idx|
      if prc.call(self[idx],self[idx+1]) == 1
        self[idx],self[idx+1] = self[idx+1], self[idx]
        self.bubble_sort(&prc) 
      end
    end

    self
    end
end
```

## Test Code

`[4, 12, 2, 8, 1, 14, 9, 25, 24, 81].bubble_sort` returns the expected results of `[1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 12, 14, 24, 25, 81]`

`[4, 12, 2, 8, 1, 14, 9, 25, 24, 81].bubble_sort { |a, b| a.to_s <=> b.to_s }` returns a stack level too deep error instead of the expected result of `[1, 12, 14, 2, 24, 25, 4, 8, 81, 9]`

Comment: I don't know what the issue is, but if you pass a proc that is the same as the default proc, it works. So it's something to do with the content of the proc, not the passing of the custom proc

Comment: Oh ok, I see the discrepancy. Your method ends up calling the proc with `81, nil`. However `81 <=> nil == nil` while `'81' <=> nil.to_s == 1`. That difference must be what's causing the infinite loop

Comment: Gosh, this took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out. THANK YOU! I fixed by adding t`&& idx+1 != self.length`  to the end of my conditional.

Comment: Perfect, I will write an answer explaining it anyway

Comment: `&prc` converts `prc` to a proc, but since `prc` is already a proc `&prc` is the same as `prc`. I suggest to write `bubble_sort!(prc = Proc.new{|a,b| a <=> b})`, which gives the argument `prc` a default value. I changed `bubble_sort` to `bubble_sort!` because your code modifies the receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with your passing of the proc, but rather that is that `<=>` works differently on numbers and strings.

When your loop gets to the end of the array, `self.idx` is equal to `self.length - 1` and `self.idx + 1` is equal to `self.length`. Calling `self[self.length]` on an array will always be nil, because of zero-indexing.

So, you end up calling `proc.call(<last element of array>, nil)`

The behavior of the spaceship operator differs depending on if you do `number <=> nil` or `number.to_s <=> nil.to_s` (which is the difference between the two procs you're comparing):

```
81 <=> nil
# => nil

81.to_s <=> nil.to_s
# => 1
```

In your case, you don't want any comparison with nil to result in a swap, so you have two options:

1. You can change the proc to return `nil` if the second element is nil:

   ```
   arr.bubble_sort do |a,b|
     b.nil? ? nil : a.to_s <=> b.to_s
   end
   ```
2. You can just skip the comparison altogether if `b` is out-of-bounds:

   ```
   self.each_with_index do |ele,idx|
     next if idx + 1 == self.length
     # ... other stuff
   ```

Comment: Perhaps #3: `self.each_index.each_cons(2) do |i1, i2| ...`.